fzf, fzf-tab, zsh, tmux, alacritty config
this is my .zshrc configuration, ctrl + t, ctrl + r but no matter what i do i can't get tab completion in tmux
even ftb-tmux-popup command run's the tmux + fzf-tab but automatically i can't invoke tab to ftb-tmux.
ctrl + t is opening simple tmux floating window to show the result but i wan't it invoke in my code with tab key
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

ZINIT_HOME="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-${HOME}/.local/share}/zinit/zinit.git"

if [ ! -d "$ZINIT_HOME" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$(dirname $ZINIT_HOME)"
  git clone https://github.com/zdharma-continuum/zinit.git "$ZINIT_HOME"
fi

source "$ZINIT_HOME/zinit.zsh"

# install plugins
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light Aloxaf/fzf-tab


export FZF_TMUX=1
export TERM=screen-256color  # This must match tmux's terminal type


# snippets
zinit snippet OMZP::git
zinit snippet OMZP::tmux

zinit ice depth=1; zinit light romkatv/powerlevel10k

# Key bindings for fzf
zinit ice depth=1
zinit light junegunn/fzf

# Enable completion and suggestions
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

zinit cdreplay -q

# according history cycle
bindkey '^[[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '^[[B' history-beginning-search-forward
bindkey '^I' expand-or-complete  # Ensure Tab key is properly mapped



# history
HISTSIZE=1000
HITFILE=~/.zsh_history
SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
HISTDUP=erase
setopt appendhistory
setopt sharehistory
setopt hist_ignore_space
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups
setopt hist_save_no_dups
setopt hist_find_no_dups

# completion style
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
# disable sort when completing `git checkout`
zstyle ':completion:*:git-checkout:*' sort false
# set descriptions format to enable group support
# NOTE: don't use escape sequences (like '%F{red}%d%f') here, fzf-tab will ignore them
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '[%d]'
# set list-colors to enable filename colorizing
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
# force zsh not to show completion menu, which allows fzf-tab to capture the unambiguous prefix
zstyle ':completion:*' menu no
zstyle ':completion:*' use-fzf-tab
# preview directory's content with ls when completing cd
zstyle ':fzf-tab:complete:cd:*' fzf-preview 'ls --color=always $realpath'

zstyle ':fzf-tab:*' fzf-command ftb-tmux-popup


alias ls='ls --color'

[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh


